# How can I search Google for ">>"

Tags: google-search

I was trying to discover what `>>` meant in java, I think it's some sort of operation but not sure, so I typed it into Google: `Java ">>"` and got the same results as for just `Java`.

Is there any way to search for special characters, like same way to 'break' like how `\"` is used to store `"` in a `String` instead of ending the String.

Answer (score 4):

Keep it simple and spell it out. For example:

- "java two greater than signs"
- "java double greater than signs"

Would both work.  The same concept works for finding out what `||` means in bash:

- "bash two pipes"

When in doubt, sound it out.

Answer (score 3):

A search for term `java operators`
brought me here

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

the symbol, according to the table:

```
shift   << >> >>>
```

or

```
assignment  = += -= *= /= %= &= ^= |= <<= >>= >>>=
```

also on stack overflow

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154553/the-command-break-in-java-what-if